# Update statement in mysql not working although it is correct?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "UPDATE reservations SET status = '$this->status',remaining_time ='$this->remain',cost = '$this->cost' WHERE id = '$this->id'";
```

This code is not working although it's correct

I am using object oriented php.
`$this->id` is a variable passed by link from another page.

When I run the code it tells me it was successful but that there are zero affected rows.

The one line above is part of the following code:

```
<?php
class edit {
    private $status;
    private $remain;
    private $cost;
    private $id;
    public function edit_data() {
        $this->status = strtoupper(strip_tags($_POST['status']));
        $this->remain = strip_tags($_POST['remain']);
        $this->cost   = strip_tags($_POST['cost']);
        $submit       = $_POST['submit'];
        $this->id     = $_GET['edit'];
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
        or die("Failed to connect to the server: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("Users")
        or die("Failed to connect to the database: " . mysql_error());
        if($submit) {
            if($this->status and $this->remain and $this->cost) {
                $sql = "UPDATE reservations SET status = '".$this->status."',remaining_time ='".$this->remain."',cost = '".$this->cost."' WHERE id = '".$this->id."'";
                $query = mysql_query($sql,$con);
                if(!$query) {
                    echo("Could not update data: " . mysql_error());
                }   
                echo "<h4>Customer reservation data has been updated successfully.</h4>";
                echo "Number of affected rows: " . mysql_affected_rows();
            }   
            else {
                echo "Please fill in all fields.";
            }
        }
        mysql_close($con);
    }   
}
$edit = new edit();
echo $edit->edit_data();
?>
```

Comment: `This code is not working although it's correct` <= funny, I'm saying it's incorrect.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: One line of code just doesn't cut it *for me*.

Comment: Where is the code that issues this query? where is the code that checks for errors after issuing this query?? Where is the dump of `$this` to prove vaiables exists and have values set??? Post your real code or you are going to get the question closed!!

Comment: *Harsh Joshi ... I tried this ... still not working –  Hamada Hosny 1 min ago* - You see how you have everyone "guessing"? Do as @RiggsFolly said and post your real/full code. However, now it's been closed and will now take more time to reopen it. *Live & learn*, like my 'ol Pappy used to say ;-)

Comment: Sorry, Iam new in the website. i tried to post code. sorry for not organizing because it's the first time to use this website.

Comment: I have posted the code to see it. please help?

Comment: You are getting `$this->id = $_GET['edit'];` and all the other data from `$_POST` **that looks like an error to me**

Comment: RiggsFolly ..... because i get the id from another page using link ... and the POST used to get data from the same page(FORM HTML) to be edited using the id from the other page

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about your concatenation? 
`$sql = "UPDATE reservations SET status = '$this->status',remaining_time ='$this->remain',cost = '$this->cost' WHERE id = '$this->id'";`
Print `$sql` to see the value.

If your database is already updated, you will receive 0 affected lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure but try this,

```
"UPDATE reservations SET status = '".$this->status."',remaining_time ='".$this->remain."',cost = '".$this->cost."' WHERE id = '".$this->id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your table doesn't contain a value which satisfies where condition.

You can check this by executing a simple query.

```
   $sql = "select * from reservations where id='$this->id'";
```